# Now 5 months waiting for 7 working day Twitch partner application

Tags: twitch.tv

I really don't see that this question offers much value but I really don't know what to do at this point. I applied for Twitch partnership since I well qualified for all the requirements and was told, as everyone is, that I would need to wait 7 working days. I contacted them after 90 working days and just got an automatic message. Responding to that automatic message yielded the same message again.

Other streamers I know of have become new members and have already been granted partnership status during my wait, within a fraction of the time. I realise I may not be given partnership status but I think I should be informed either way, rather than just waiting endlessly.

If they state it should be seven days should it not in fact be that or at least thereabouts? At two months it was ridiculous, at four it was insane, now coming up to six months I don't have even words for it.

Has anyone had a similar experience or any idea what I can do? It seems like it must be some kind of error, this simply can't be normal..

Comment: It's opinion-based because it's asking for others' experiences, not for a solution to a specific problem about using a web app.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit.  If you disagree with the closure please review [Closed Questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) and also [What if I disagree with the closure of a question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148862/discussion-on-question-by-hasen-now-5-months-waiting-for-7-working-day-twitch-pa); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.